# Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD GitHub log file location

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, github

iam using  Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD with github
i am getting this error while building my vuejs

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2021-06-13T15_50_31_287Z-debug.log

where can i find this log file?

Comment: This is not the actual error, paste the whole error

Comment: where can i find this link  /github/home/.npm/_logs/2021-06-13T15_50_31_287Z-debug.log , the complete link?